# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' when installing gpt-engineer

Tags: python-3.x, pip, openai-api

**Issue Description**:
Steps to Reproduce:

Run the command `pip install gpt-engineer` in the directory `"C:\Users\Lu-Cash\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Test"`.
Observe the error message.

**Expected Behavior**:
I expected the gpt-engineer package to be installed successfully without any errors.

**Actual Behavior**:
I encountered the following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GDWU.png)

**Environment**:

```
Operating System: Windows 11 Home Single Language
Python Version: 3.11.3
Other relevant software versions: N/A
```

**Attempted Solutions**:
I have tried the following solutions, but none of them resolved the issue:

1. Ensured that `Python` and `pip` are installed and properly
   configured.
2. Verified that the `pip` executable is available in the Python
   installation directory.
3. Upgraded `pip` to the latest version using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

I appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you for your attention.

When running the command `pip install gpt-engineer`, you are expecting the following to happen:

- The package gpt-engineer should be downloaded from the Python Package
  Index (PyPI) or another specified source.
- The required dependencies for gpt-engineer should be resolved and
  installed automatically.
- The installation process should complete without any errors or
  issues.
- After the installation, you should be able to import and use the
  gpt-engineer package in your Python scripts or interactive sessions.

In summary, the expected outcome is a successful installation of the gpt-engineer package, allowing you to utilize its functionalities in your Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use venv to use a virtual environment instead global one.

```py
python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
pip install gpt-engineer
```

Or use in terminal REPL using command Python and ENTER:

```
>> import pip
```

If return a problem, visit the website pip installation [Install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

Comment: C:\Users\Lu-Cash\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\chatGPT\gpt-engineer>python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: step 1 - python -m venv .venv 
step 2 - source .venv/bin/activate
See documentation [pip](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: @RoniMaciel as you can see clearly on the paths, OP is using Windows. So, your solution may help, but you need to change the calls to `py -m pip install --user virtualenv` and `py -m venv env` and `.\env\Scripts\activate` as seen in your link you have provided.